# docker-compose local variable declare and use

Tags: docker-compose

In the programming language we can define and declare a **variable** and use it later in the program, can we do same in **docker-compose** file?

#### For example in Java:

int **x** = 100; 
System.out.println("Number is: "+ **x**); 
Similarly, in docker-compose file, can we declare a local variables and use it later.

#### docker-compose file

In the docker-compose file we want to declare **tomcat_home** as a variable and use it later as shown in example.

`values:
  - tomcat_home: "/usr/local/tomcat"`

# Creating Tomcat Server 1

Server1:
  image: tomcat
  hostname: TomcatServer1
  container_name: TomcatServer1
  volumes:
    - ${PWD}/tomcat-users.xml:**${tomcat_home}**/conf/tomcat-users.xml
    - ${PWD}/server.xml:**${tomcat_home}**/conf/server.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

One could set a variable in an .env file:

```
TAG=1.2.3
```

and call it in a docker-compose file

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:${TAG}
    ports:
    - 80:80
```

docker-compose up

returns:

```
Pulling web (nginx:1.2.3)...
ERROR: manifest for nginx:1.2.3 not found
```

No need to run docker-compose to check the config

According to the documentation one could run:

```
docker-compose config
```

to verify the docker-compose config

```
networks: {}
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:1.2.3
    ports:
    - 80:80/tcp
version: '3.0'
volumes: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `docker-compose`, you can use either the environment or a `.env` file. For swarm mode, you can only use the environment. So for portability, I like to export variables into the shell or environment of the command being run.

From a bash shell, this would look like:

```
$ export tomcat_home=/usr/local/tomcat
$ docker-compose up
```

Depending on what you use to deploy your containers (shell script, custom code, some other CI/CD tool), exporting your environment variable will vary.